# How do we send an SMTP email using AWS from my JAVA (Android studio) app

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, smtp, gmail-imap

I suspect it is my transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD); line. I think there is no connection established at all. My code currently looks like this:

```
private void sendEmail(String messegeToSend) {

    final String FROM = "joe.blogs@mydomain.com";
    final String FROMNAME = "Joe Blogs";
    final String TO = "joe.blogs@joeblogs.com";
    final String HOST = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
    final int PORT = 587;
    final String SMTP_USERNAME = "smtpusername";
    final String SMTP_PASSWORD = "smtppassword";

    try {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(TO));
        message.setSubject("InvoiceRequest");
        message.setText(messegeToSend);
        Transport transport = session.getTransport();

        transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connected!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

    }catch (MessagingException e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry, We ran into a problem"+ e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        throw  new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

At the end of it all, I want to finally send an email from within this app. I was previously using Google's Gmail SMTP but it is to be decommissioned, hence  I have switched to
AWS SES, which I am now struggling with.

Comment: I don't know why you think GMail SMTP is decommissioned (it's not) but what errors are you getting?  Are you sure you want to put credentials such as username/password into your application?  If someone decompiled your app they could send email as you.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same exact problem you had too.

**Networking operations, like transport.connect(), have to be ran in Threads too**! Making a network request on the main thread will cause the thread to wait, or block. Thus, the problem to your solution would be to extend the AmazonSESSample class to the Thread class.

**Step 1)** I am assuming that you have **followed the steps provided on Amazon's AWS documentation to send emails programmatically through Amazon SES SMTP interface**. If not here is the link to it: [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-using-smtp-programmatically.html).

**Step 2)** Download and import the following jar files if you have yet to do so:

> https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1q5n2ROQvlmvkW7DAWyhGxzceRustouhK?usp=sharing

**Step 3)** Add the following implementations to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies{
implementation files('libs\\javax.mail.jar')
implementation files('libs\\javax.activation.jar')
implementation files('libs\\javax.additionnal.jar')
}
```

**Step 4)** Instead of following the code they provided, this is the modified version that worked:

```
import android.os.Build;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public class AmazonSESSample extends Thread{

    // Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
    // This address must be verified.
    static final String FROM = "sender@example.com";
    static final String FROMNAME = "Sender Name";
    
    // Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account 
    // is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
    static final String TO = "recipient@example.com";
    
    // Replace smtp_username with your Amazon SES SMTP user name.
    static final String SMTP_USERNAME = "smtp_username";
    
    // Replace smtp_password with your Amazon SES SMTP password.
    static final String SMTP_PASSWORD = "smtp_password";
    
    // The name of the Configuration Set to use for this message.
    // If you comment out or remove this variable, you will also need to
    // comment out or remove the header below.
    static final String CONFIGSET = "ConfigSet";
    
    // Amazon SES SMTP host name. This example uses the US West (Oregon) region.
    // See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html#region-endpoints
    // for more information.
    static final String HOST = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
    
    // The port you will connect to on the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint. 
    static final int PORT = 587;
    
    static final String SUBJECT = "Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using Java)";
    
    static final String BODY = String.join(
            System.getProperty("line.separator"),
            "<h1>Amazon SES SMTP Email Test</h1>",
            "<p>This email was sent with Amazon SES using the ", 
            "<a href='https://github.com/javaee/javamail'>Javamail Package</a>",
            " for <a href='https://www.java.com'>Java</a>."
        );

    public void run() {

        // Create a Properties object to contain connection configuration information.
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        // Create a Session object to represent a mail session with the specified properties. 
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        // Create a message with the specified information. 
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM,FROMNAME));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
        msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
        msg.setContent(BODY,"text/html");
        
        // Add a configuration set header. Comment or delete the 
        // next line if you are not using a configuration set
        msg.setHeader("X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET", CONFIGSET);
            
        // Create a transport.
        Transport transport = session.getTransport();
                    
        // Send the message.
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Sending...");
            
            // Connect to Amazon SES using the SMTP username and password you specified above.
            transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
            
            // Send the email.
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("Email sent!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
            System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close and terminate the connection.
            transport.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**It is important that you have imported the following jar libraries into your project too:**

1. javax.activation.jar
2. javax.additionnal.jar
3. javax.mail.jar